# convert double type into string type in arduino sketch

Tags: string, arduino, double

```
double ambientTemp=44.00;
String yourdatacolumn="yourdata=";
String yourdata; 
double yourarduinodata=ambientTemp; 
yourdata = yourdatacolumn + yourarduinodata;
```

I want the output to be string but because of yourarduinodata is double type. Can not convert it to string. Then , I put (String) in front of yourarduinodata, still doesn't let me run throught.

Anyone has any idea about convert double type into string type in arduino sketch?

Answer (score 17):

Use - `String(val, decimalPlaces)`

example,

```
double a = 10.2010;

String SerialData="";

SerialData = String(a,4);

Serial.println(SerialData);
```

Answer (score 11):

Another Way To Convert Double To String:

```
    char TempString[10];  //  Hold The Convert Data

    dtostrf(ambientTemp,2,2,TempString);
 // dtostrf( [doubleVar] , [sizeBeforePoint] , [sizeAfterPoint] , [WhereToStoreIt] )
    YourArduinoData = String(TempString);  // cast it to string from char
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work:

```
String double2string(double n, int ndec) {
    String r = "";

    int v = n;
    r += v;     // whole number part
    r += '.';   // decimal point
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<ndec;i++) {
        // iterate through each decimal digit for 0..ndec 
        n -= v;
        n *= 10; 
        v = n;
        r += v;
    }

    return r;
}
```